# identify duplicates in a column then find the maximum value of adjacent column values in excel

Tags: excel, duplicates, max

This is a constantly growing file of part names. Each time a part is revised a new test part needs to be made of the revision so we want to keep track of the highest level

Based on duplicates in column A, I am trying to show the current highest rev level (alphanumeric) from column B in column C.

Using the code command I can get a value for the Rev Level up to Z, But I need to account for revision levels beyond Z (AA or AB etc)

[image: sample spreadsheet]

```
PN         rev Max Code
1-QR-728    -   C   45
4-QR-63     D   D   68
2-QR-312    C   D   67
1-QR-728    A   C   65
28-QR-240   A   K   65
2-QR-312    D   D   68
6-QR-257    AA  AB  65
1-QR-728    B   C   66
28-QR-240   K   K   75
4-QR-198    -   -   45
1-QR-728    C   C   67
5-QR-223    D   D   68
6-QR-257    AB  AB  65
```

Comment: how do you add the actual data sample? I tried pasting the file

Comment: Thank you, I admit Im a newbie

Comment: Here is an example [markdown table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) which can also be used at times

Comment: What is the range of values that revisions can take?

Comment: At present they look a bit like they match up with column names in which case you could do =IFERROR(COLUMN(INDIRECT(B3&"1")),0) etc to return a number and play around with that in an array formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that goes in column F and uses a helper column E.

Example in `F3`

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MAX(IF($A$3:$A$15=A3,$E$3:$E$15)),4),"1",""),"-")
```

entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and dragged down.

And in column E, example `E3`

```
=IFERROR(COLUMN(INDIRECT(B3&"1")),0)
```

It is based on the revisions matching up with available column names.

[image: Data in sheet]

Comment: It works Perfectly!, It took me a few minutes to figure out what it does, but it should work for additional part numbers and revisions. Thank you